# React Redux Setup for Slider Status

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a left Sidebar that I want to share State of throughout my application so if user clicks on slider's button, user can make it hidden or show. Initially I plan to have it shown. I was following a Redux course and in the coure they did an example of fetching posts from API which is entirely different thant what I need so I am puzzled here...

So far, I created a folder called actions with 2 files,
sliderActions.js

```
import { Slider } from "./types"

export function sliderUpdate() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch({
            status: "hidden"
        })
    }
}
```

and types.js

```
export const Slider = "Slider";
```

reducers folder has two files
index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux"
import postReducer from "./postReducer"

export default combineReducers({
    posts: postReducer
})
```

and postReducer.js

```
import { Slider } from "./../actions/types"

const initialState = {
    Slider: "hide"
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

store.js file

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux"
import { thunk } from "redux-thunk"
import rootReducer from "./reducers"

const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer, 
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)
)

export default store
```

and lastly 
I imported below two to the App.js

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { store } from "./store"
```

and wrapped my whole code inside return statement of App with a `<Provider store={store}>` and `</Provider>`

I am entirely new to the redux and don't know how to get this working, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation says: **Actions may not have an undefined "type" property.**

Change your action in your sliderUpdate function and add 'type' key.

For example:

```
dispatch({
   type: "SLIDER_BUTTON_CLICKED",
   status: "hidden",
});
```

and now you want to change your postReducer to:

```
const initialState = {
    slider: "opened"
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "SLIDER_BUTTON_CLICKED": {
            return {...state, slider: action.status}
        }

        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actions must have a type property that indicates the **type** of action being performed. Types should typically be defined as string constants.

So your actions file should be something like this

```
import { SLIDER } from "../constant/slide";

export function sliderUpdate() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch({
      type: SLIDER,
      status: "hidden"
    });
  };
}
```

Where the constant SLIDER

```
export const SLIDER = "SLIDER";
```

And the reducer should look like this

```
import { SLIDER } from "../constant/slide";

const initialState = {
  Slider: "hide"
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SLIDER:
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.data);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

We don't mutate the state.So We create a copy with `Object.assign()` where it will contain the new data.